# adding Powerpoint Add-in from registry throws " Powerpoint couldn't load the file" error

Tags: vba, registry, powerpoint, add-in

*I created Powerpoint Add-in using VBA. I added it manually to Powerpoint and it works fine, When I start Powerpoint, I can see it's loaded and working as expected. I want this add-in to load through registry. Below is my registry file detail. But it throws error* **"For some reason Powerpoint couldn't load the file"**

#

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\PowerPoint\Addins\MyNewAddIn]
"AutoLoad"=dword:ffffffff 
"Path"="file:///C:/MyAddinFolder/MyNewAddIn.ppam"
```

Comment: *I want this add-in to load through registry* - huh? like a COM add-in? it's *not* a COM add-in.

Comment: Power Point add in

Comment: Yes, exactly: not a COM add-in. It doesn't work like that.

Comment: ohh... So only COM add-in can be configured .. Not PowerPoint Add-in ?

http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00469_Add_-_install_an_addin_via_the_registry.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, here's the registry entry for one of my installed add-ins:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\PowerPoint\AddIns\RESIZE]
"Path"="C:\\Users\\steve\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\AddIns\\RESIZE.PPA"
"AutoLoad"=dword:ffffffff
```

Yours:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\PowerPoint\Addins\MyNewAddIn]
"AutoLoad"=dword:ffffffff 
"Path"="file:///C:/MyAddinFolder/MyNewAddIn.ppam"
```

Note the differences in the Path entry.

Comment: Thanks it worked. The error was in file path. I changed it to "Path"="C:\\Controller\\registry\\CloseExtraWindow.ppam" and it now loads on start up.